# Calculating the average of last N records of a table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a MySQL table in which the pricing data of a some companies are stored:

```
| Field            | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
| id               | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| company_id       | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| company_name     | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| time_stamp       | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date             | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| shamsi_date      | varchar(12)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| final_price      | decimal(10,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

MySQL Version: 8.0.14

There are 2048 company IDs and pricing data is updated daily. I want to perform the following steps:

1. Get the last N prices of each company. N is 30. But some companies may have fewer data, i.e. 18 days or 23 days,
2. Calculating the average of these prices for each company,
3. and finally put it in another row of another table.

I have written the following code to do so:

```
public HashMap<Long, Double> getMeanVolume() {

    HashMap<Long, Double> volumeList = new HashMap<Long, Double>();

    double sum = 0;

    int pageSize = 30;


    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<DailyEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(DailyEntity.class);

    Root<DailyEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(DailyEntity.class);

    criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.select(root);

    // Sorting
    criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get("shamsiDate")));

    ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list = getCompanyID();

    for (Long com_id : list) {

        sum = 0;

        // Selecting
        Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("companyID"), com_id);
        criteriaQuery.where(predicate);

        // Now everything should be gathered together in a TypedQuery:
        TypedQuery<DailyEntity> typedQuery = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

        // Pagination settings
        typedQuery.setFirstResult(0);
        typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);

        // Getting Results. Here as we have Payment as the root element, we have
        // can get a list of Payments.
        List<DailyEntity> results = typedQuery.getResultList();

        if (results.isEmpty())
            continue;

        for (DailyEntity entit : results) {

            sum += entit.getLegal().getNaturalSellVol() + entit.getLegal().getLegalSellVol();

        }
        volumeList.put(com_id.longValue(), sum / results.size());
        log.info(com_id.toString());

    }

    // volumeList.forEach((key, value) -> {System.out.println(key + " " + value);});

    return volumeList;

}
```

This code works but it is very slow. Calculating each average takes about 0.6 seconds.

1. Is it possible to perform this calculation with some SQL queries. I think it will be faster.
2. How can  I improve this code?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: .. also in this case knowing the MySQL version which you use also might be important -> `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks, I've added some information.

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8 by any chance?

Comment: But not the requested information :-(

Comment: @SalmanA yes, I mentioned the version.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks, what else should I tell?

Comment: @ImanH MySQL 8 supports window functions so something like `WITH cte AS (SELECT company_id, final_price, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn FROM tablename) SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn <= 30` will give you last 30 prices per-compay. Calculating the average is as-easy as adding a sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way
In your repository

```
@Query("SELECT AVG(final_price)  FROM (SELECT final_price FROM companies ORDER BY company_id DESC LIMIT ?1)")
Double getAverageOfLastNRecords(int n);
```